# requesting free keyword database for demo application

Tags: database, web-scraping

I need a database of human readable information, at least 10k records.

Preferably with category + title

Need recommendations of free databases / csv, I'd rather not scrape.

regards,
/t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data.gov has loads of freely available data in CSV format. It may have something like what you are looking for.

http://explore.data.gov/catalog/raw/

Edit: Here are couple more to look at:

http://aws.amazon.com/datasets

http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to generate something nifty here: http://www.generatedata.com
And here's a site listing various resources: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/test-sample-data-generators